# jOOQ + Scala: Plain SQL Field will not compile

Tags: java, scala, jooq

I'm on Scala 2.13, JDK 17 and jOOQ 3.18.5 (also tried jOOQ 3.15.12 w/ JDK 11).

I can't seem to get Plain SQL working, I get this error when compiling:

```
> Task :project:compileScala
[Error] : Unable to locate class corresponding to inner class entry for Publisher in owner java.util.concurrent.Flow
```

There is no stack trace, but by process of elimination I narrowed it down to the field instantiation. When I comment out the query and the `DSL.using`, the error still happens, but when I comment out the fields as well it compiles fine.

Scala code:

```scala
import org.jooq.impl.DSL._
import org.jooq._
import org.jooq.impl._
```

```scala
val source = field("source")
```

I also tried giving the field a type but had the same error.

Within the same project, I can create fields in a Java class file without an issue. The error only happens when trying to use fields in Scala.

How can I get jOOQ to cooperate with Scala?

Comment: are you using [jooq-scala](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jooq/jooq-scala_2.13/3.18.6) as dependency? based on [getting started with jooq and scala](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/jooq-and-scala/) not sure if you also need to import `import org.jooq.scalaextensions.Conversions._`. If that is not the case, please edit your post trying to provide more context. A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible.

Comment: jOOQ's own Scala integration tests don't hint at any such problem, so a complete reproducer would be very useful. jOOQ has a template for such reproducers: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ-mcve

Comment: @GastónSchabas ah, I actually completely missed they even had that in the docs. thanks for the link!